# CSS help: how to format code block and code line?

Tags: css, markdown

I notice code block which is tagged with

```
<pre><code>this is my code block</code></pre>
```

and code line which is tagged with`<code>this is code line</code>` when Markdown converted to HTML.

Stack-overflow or Github has implemented such kind of css style. So I hacked Github css file:
http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/shared/css/documentation.css

Simply using below style doesn't work:

```
code {
  font: 12px Monaco,"Courier New","DejaVu Sans Mono","Bitstream Vera Sans Mono",monospace;
  color: #52595d;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}


pre {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font: 12px Monaco,"Courier New","DejaVu Sans Mono","Bitstream Vera Sans Mono",monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #FAFAFB;
  color: #393939;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

The test html code is below:

````
<body>
<p>This is <code>code</code> style.</p>

<pre><code>Dude, here is code line.
The second line.
signing off.
</code></pre>

<ul>
<li><p>If you&rsquo;re using Git you might want to add the following
configuration setting to protect your project from Windows line
endings creeping in:</p>

<pre><code>```$ git config --global core.autocrlf true```
</code></pre></li>
</ul>

</body>
````

Any idea?

---

Firstly, thank all. sorry, I don't understand the two tags `pre` and `code`, as well don't understand how the two tags mapping to block-level code and inline code.

For block-level code, `<pre>` tag is used for it even though `<code>` is after `<pre>`, I must write `pre { ... }` alone.

For inline code, `<code>` tag is used for it, this tag parent might be `<p>`, `<li>`. so I could use **the element>element selector** in order to distinguish `<pre><code>`.

Apply them, it works now.

Thanks,
Kuaf

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work? The style sheet has some effects. What is wrong with them? The effects are not identifical with those of Git, since the style sheets are different. For example, you are setting `color` on `code` but the Git CSS file sets it on `p code`.

Comment: I use [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) to convert markdown to HTML. Meanwhile, this tool could inline CSS style file to HTML. I like Github-style code block and code line and want to refine <pre><code> and <code> simply. I cannot add extra `class` property to these tags. With my css definition, browser don't identify <pre><code> and <code> well.

Comment: I think there's a library called `prism.js` which uses this kind of format to format code

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is distinguishing between `<pre><code>` and `<code>`, as you say in a comment, then the solution is to use a CSS rule of the form

```
pre code { /* declarations here */ }
```

for those properties that should apply to `code` only when it is inside `pre`. There you can override any settings in a rule that has only `code` as the selector.

Comment: Thank you, actually, I've tried `pre code { ... }` you mentioned above, it doesn't work, you can have a try. I tested in IE8 and Firefox, both failed, only `code { ... }` is used by browser.

Comment: @kuaf if you post the code that you tried, maybe someone can isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `code` and `pre` to `.code` and `.pre` in the css, and then change the following:

````
<body>
<p>This is <code>code</code> style.</p>

<span class="pre"><span class="code">Dude, here is code line.
The second line.
signing off.
</span></span>

<ul>
<li><p>If you&rsquo;re using Git you might want to add the following
configuration setting to protect your project from Windows line
endings creeping in:</p>

<span class="pre"><span class="code">```$ git config --global core.autocrlf true```
</span></span></li>
</ul>

</body>
````

The span tage is very useful, as it does nothing by default. This means that by changing the class, you can format it any way you want using css

Comment: I cannot change the HTML tag itself, because it's the output of [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) tool. What I can do is to define the CSS style file and inline to HTML.

Comment: I attempt to find solution from [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) side. However, they don't help me out of this issue. I must make browser distinguish <pre><code> and <code>.

Comment: I'm using the code and pre css definitions the OP provided, and the .code .pre syntax that annonymously suggested, and have to say it's working just fine. Have an upvote!